Azure pipeline: Azure CLI 2: how to provide parameters in az sub deployment create command?
In my inline script I want to pass my string variable in the paremeter section of the az cli command. I know something like that works:
preDeploymentRgListName='myRgName1myRgName2' \
But I would like to use a var instead.
Below I convert my bash array to string with loop or printf but I can't find a way to pass it correctly into the az cli sub deployment command because my code doesn't do what I want.If I use a hardcoded value like above, it work.
Here's my code:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  condition: ${{ containsValue(parameters.deployStages, 'connectivite') }}
  displayName: 'Create/Update Platform Hub'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $(var-bashPreInjectScript)

      templateFile=hub/hubconnectivite.bicep

      echo "Deploying $templateFile using ${{ parameters.deployOperation }} operation"
      
      preDeploymentRgList=$(az group list --subscription "$(var-hub-subscriptionId)" --query "[].name")

      bash_array=($(echo "$preDeploymentRgList" | jq -r '.[]'))

      for item in "${bash_array[@]}"
      do
      string+=$item
      done
      echo "string: $string"

      printf -v string1 "${bash_array[@]}"
      echo "${string1}"

      az deployment sub ${{ parameters.deployOperation }} \
        --name hubconnectivite${{ parameters.deploymentRegion }} \
        --location ${{ parameters.deploymentRegion }} \
        --subscription $(var-hub-subscriptionId) \
        --template-file $templateFile \
        --parameters \
            subscriptionId='$(var-hub-subscriptionId)' \
            location='${{ parameters.deploymentRegion }}' \
            resourceGroups='$(var-hub-resourceGroups)' \
            preDeploymentRgListName='$(string1)' \
            ddosProtection='$(var-hub-ddosProtection)' \
            virtualNetworks='$(var-hub-virtualNetworks)' \
            egressVirtualApplianceIp='$(var-hub-egressVirtualApplianceIp)' \
            routeTables='$(var-hub-routeTables)' \
            keyVaults='$(var-hub-keyVault)' \
            apiManagements='$(var-hub-apiManagements)' \
            nsgList='$(var-hub-nsgList)' \
            natGateway='$(var-hub-natgateway)' \
            vpn='$(var-hub-vpn)' \
            appGateways='$(var-hub-appGateways)' \
            bastionHost='$(var-hub-bastionHost)' \
            rgtags='$(var-common-rgtags)' \
            usersAssigned='$(var-hub-usersAssigned)' \
            rtags='$(var-hub-rtags)'

      $(var-bashPostInjectScript)
    workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDir }}'


"If I use a hardcoded value like above, it work" - Double-check if all the parameters and variables have the right values. Add a dummy task to print their values before the AzureCLI@2 task.

@RuiJarimba ok i'm trying this


Azure pipeline: Azure CLI 2: how to provide parameters in az sub deployment create command?

I have used below script it worked for me:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  rith_hd_vl: 'rithwik,rithpyser'

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Rithwik Test'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'rithres'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      rith_hd_vl='$(rith_hd_vl)'
      echo "Hello Rithwik, Hardcoded Value is: $rith_hd_vl"

      rith_rg_list=$(az group list --subscription "ACES BOJJA" --query "[].name" -o tsv)
      echo "Hello Rithwik, Output of az group list cmd is : $rith_rg_list"

      ri_dv=$(echo "$rith_rg_list" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
      echo "Dynamic Value (Comma-Separated): $ri_dv"

Used this ri_dv=$(echo "$rith_rg_list" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//') to make it similar to hard
One has to modify the output according to the requirement
Output:

